# How to remove Warning "local variable 'tmp' returned " on operator overloading?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, g++

When I compile my solution in Android (Tegra NDK Compiler) or Linux (g++), I get this warning on GRPPOINT operator overloading. However, I do not get it on Visual Studio (cl).

```
  ../../../Gen/Graphic/GRPPoint.h: In member function 'GRPPOINT& GRPPOINT::operator/(GLFLOAT)':
D:\Projects\Gen\Graphic\GRPPoint.h(86,22): warning : reference to local variable 'tmp' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
               GRPPOINT tmp;
```

The code is an operator overloading for the Class GRPPOINT:

```
GRPPOINT& operator / (GLFLOAT scalar)
{
GRPPOINT tmp;
tmp.x   =   this->x /scalar;
tmp.y   =   this->y /scalar;
tmp.z   =   this->z /scalar;
return tmp;
}
```

Seems that copying by reference of the object tmp is not allowed. 
I might be confusing the use of the &.
The code works fine, and does what it should, but I dont know how to overcome this warning.

Thanks.

Comment: so, as I understand from the "duplicate" is that I might be using freed memory, despise I ask the return to copy it? I dont get it, how should I do the operator overloading?

Comment: return by value `GRPPOINT` not `GRPPOINT&`

Comment: The "&" in "GRPPOINT&" means that you're *not* copying it, only referencing it. Remove the "&".

Comment: thank you, paste it as answer so I can mark it